# Confusion on the constant sheaf in Vakil's THE RISING SEA book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have hard time understanding the definition of constant sheaf in the book:

(consider the sheaf on topological space $X$ of category $C$ where $C$ is the category Sets, $U$ is any open subset of $X$, and $S$ is an object in $C$)

Let $\mathscr F(U)$ be the maps to $S$ that are locally constant, i.e., for any point $p$ in $U$, there is an open neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ where *the function is constant*.

The question is: what does the author mean, *"the function is constant"*? I'm trying to guess that it means $\mathscr F(U_p) = S$ for any p with $S$ fixed at the beginning, but I fail to prove that $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf.

(Maybe that is one silly question, but I do look up to Wikipedia and browse on the related questions at MSE, and sadly I just cannot figure out the right definition...I am a novice and don't know what a sheafication is...)

Comment: It's the sheafification of the presheaf that sends every nonempty set $U$ to $S$, and every restriction morphism is the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there exist $c$ such that $f$ is equal to $c$ for all values of $x$ in the neighborhood under consideration. Note that this doesn't mean that $f$ is constant on all $U$ if $U$ is not connected. $f$ locally constant on $U$ means that $f$ is constant on each of the connected components of $U$ (assuming $U$ locally connected, as pointed out by Alex Youcis in the comments).

Comment: Your last sentence is not quite correct -- one implication is true, but the reverse is not. For example, think about the identity map $\mathbb{Q}_p\to\mathbb{Q}_p$ where the target is given the discrete topology, and the source the $p$-adic topology. Your characterization works when $U$ is locally connected.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking of the case of a sheaf of real valued functions.

Comment: Why does this have anything to do with connected component? It seems to me that Vakil does not mention anything about connected component in this definition.

Comment: @coudy Even the target being real-valued doesn't help -- this is more a function of the source being locally connected.

Comment: @fufufufuf If you think about: a function $f\colon X\to S$ is locally constant if and only if it is continuosu when $S$ is endowed with the discrete topology. It's a fact that a continuous function to a discrete (or more generally totally disconnected set) factorizes through the space $\pi_0(X)$ of connected components of $X$ (essentially you need to check that a locally constant function on a connected space is constant). If $X$ is locally connected, then $\pi_0(X)$ is discrete, and so in fact the converse holds: a function $f\colon X\to S$ is locally constant if and only if it factorizes

Comment: through the set $\pi_0(X)$. But, as I mentioned above, this only works if $X$ is locally connected, which ensures that any function $\pi_0(X)\to S$ is continuous/locally constant as $\pi_0(X)$ is then discrete.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I guess your comment should be the answer. Let me delete mine.

Comment: @coudy No need to delete. Your answer is essentially correct! Just with a minor technicality at the end.

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks a lot.